# rails - can't build a record with uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, paperclip

I am trying to build a profile object like so:

```
@user.profiles.build(params[:profile])
```

When build is called, it runs the validations for `Profile` but the issue occurs when there is an image uploaded and when it is contained in `params[:profile]`

When there is an image there and build is called, the validations are run and it cannot find a user because the user_id is not passed into the proc. But if there is no image in `params[:profile]` the user_id is passed in and it finds a user.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :require_profile_name
  has_may :profiles
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :image
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, if: Proc.new { |profile| profile.user.require_profile_name }
end
```

I have found no one with the same problem looking around google, so I am at a loss about where to start.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: just a correction. when you call `build`, no validations are executed yet. validations are only ran when you call `save`, `create` or `update_attributes` (i may be missing some other methods)

Comment: You are right, but I get the `undefined method require_profile_name for nil:NilClass` when build is called. Not on `save` for sure.

Answer (score 0):

for your profile class, you need to make sure that the user is set first before you check for the validation of the name

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :image
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, if: proc { |profile| profile.user.try(:require_profile_name) }
end
```

With this, the record wont be saved if the user is not set.  If the user is set and requires a profile name, it will also fail the validation when name is blank.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the issue is the user is never set when there is a file in the profile params, for an unknown reason.

Comment: No other suggestions? I am still stumped by this.